# How to update database thruogh dropdown without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Please look at this code first:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#alternatecolor [type=button]").each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        btnObj = $(this);
        rowId = $(this).attr("rowId");
        changeStatus = $(this).attr("changeStatus");
        $.get("changeStatus.php?rowId="+rowId+"&changeStatus="+changeStatus,function(data,status){

                                    if(changeStatus == 0){
                str ="Unverify";
                btnText = "Verify";
                newStatus = 1;
            }
            else{
                str ="Verify";
                btnText = "Unverify";
                newStatus = 0;
            }

            if(data == 'success'){                  
                alert("Status updated successfully to "+str+".");
                btnObj.val(btnText);
                btnObj.attr("changeStatus",newStatus);
            }
            else{
                alert("some error");
            }
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my change status page:

```
$dbhost = 'xxxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxx';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxx');

$sql ="update experiment set verification=".$_GET['changeStatus']." where row=".$_GET['rowId'];

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(!($retval))
{
  die('error');
}
else{
    echo "success";
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

I was using a button in this code to query my database with values 0,1. If pressed once, database queried with 1, if pressed again, database queried with 0.

Now, I have to put a dropdown in place of button with 3 values to query database with: 0,1,2. If selected first value, database row to be updated with value 0 and so on.

How would I do that?

Comment: "Mysql api" is deprecated, use [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: I would go one step further @GuilhermeNascimento and use the PDO

Comment: @No1_Melman A good suggestion, but this case is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento indeed, I really like the way PDO handles getting information out of the database and places it automatically into a class.

Comment: @No1_Melman Thank you for sharing your opinion, but it is precisely for this reason I said that is a matter of opinion (the kind of "type").

Comment: Guys... I know the method I used is deprecated and using Mysqli is a good option. But here, my concern is different.

Comment: @Niks We understand, as if in answer to your question then we would add "answer" and not "comments", we just help you improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove button and add select like this:

```
<select class="my-select">
<option value="0">update</option>
<option value="1">create</option>
<option value="2">delete</option>
</select>
```

you also need to add data-rowId attribute.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".my-select").change(function() {
        btnObj = $(this);
        rowId = $(this).attr("data-rowId");
        changeStatus = $(this).val();
        $.get("changeStatus.php?rowId="+rowId+"&changeStatus="+changeStatus,function(data,status){

            if(data == 'success'){                  
                alert("Status updated successfully to "+str+".");

            }
            else{
                alert("some error");
            }

    });
});
});
```

Comment: To continue with his use of event binding, use `.on('change', function () {})`

Comment: it seems that it is not dynamically generated html. so do not need any delegate here.

Answer (score 0):

update
create
delete

You can do using class name or ID. If it's id then do `$("#id1").click(function () {...` in below code.

Awlad has done using GET method, below is using POST method.

```
        $(function () {
            $(".my-select").click(function () {
            var category = $(this).text();
            //$('label').css('color', selText);
                $.ajax({
                        url: "invite_db.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {"category": category},
                        success: function(data) {
                            $(".articleContent").html(data);

                            //setInterval("messageDisable()", 5000);
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
```

I have used parameter name according to my code. Please you change it

Answer (score 0):

Here is your HTML and Javascript code

```
<select onchange="getval(this);">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function getval(sel) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url, // url is page where you want to process this post request
      data: 'val=' + sel.value,
});
}
</script>
```

On PHP side

```
<?php
 // Your database connection code
 $val = $_POST['val'];
 mysql_query("UPDATE 'tablename' SET 'column name' = $val 'Your WHere caluse'")
?>
```